# Average Roots Word Problem

Tags: probability, dice, average

Tyler rolls two, fair, six-sided dice, one die is red and one is blue.
Calling the value of the red die *R* and the sum of the dice *S*, he then solves the equation $x^2+Rx=1$ and choose the greater solution is *S* is even and the lesser solution if *S* is odd.

What is the expected value of the solution he finds?
(I.E. The average value if he does this repeatedly.)

(I feel that the problem doesn't provide enough information; however, please correct me if I am wrong.)

Answer (score 1):

There is plenty of information.  If I told you that $R=1$ and $S$ is even, could you find the number you choose?  It is a quadratic equation.  There are twelve cases, six choices for $R$ and even/odd for $S$, all equally probable.  The pedestrian approach is to make a table of all twelve cases, add up the numbers you get, and divide by $12$.  This proves there is enough information.

There is an easier way.  Do you know something about the sum of the roots of a quadratic equation?

Comment: Not quite...is there a formula for it? How do you use it in this case?

Comment: If you add the two roots the quadratic formula gives you, the square root disappears and you are left with $-\frac ba$. That is $-R$ in your problem.